# Can we increment version of MongoDB document version manually in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-elasticsearch

We can use versionType = EXTERNAL, EXTERNAL_GTE in ElasticSearch entities to manage version of entity and @Version annotated field will be incremented manually by developer in spring-data-elasticsearch.

So, when we send any document update which has smaller version then VersionConflictEngineException will be thrown but it will let you send any version which greater then or equal(in EXTERNAL_GTE case) the current entity version.

Is there any chance to manage version of mongoDB documents in that way in spring-data-mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.optimistic-locking), you can use the @Version annotation. Be aware that the class I'm refering to is: org.springframework.data.annotation.Version, not the JPA one.

Comment: But I want to manage it manually. According to doc: It should be the same value when you want to update document otherwise OptimisticLockingFailureException will be thrown. I just want to set it in ElasticSearch way.

Comment: Then I would recommend you to create your own annotation, create an event  listener implementing the onBeforeSave method. In this method you can use reflection to check for fields with you own annotation and do the respective validation. Maybe it's a convoluted solution, but I don't know any other way.